# Getter 'Length' was called on null

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

When I open the tab, for a second, there is this error. Then it goes away, how do I solve this?
I'm assuming it takes time to generate the length value?

```
class rideList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _rideListState createState() => _rideListState();
}

class _rideListState extends State<rideList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final rides = Provider.of<List<RideDetails>>(context);
    int count = 0;

    if (rides.length != null) {
      return ListView.builder(
        itemCount: rides.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          print('Rides: ${rides.length}');
          if (rides[index].limit == true) {
            return RideTile(ride: rides[index]);
          }
          else if(rides[index].limit == false){
            ++count;
            if(rides.length == count){
              print('no rides');
              return Center(child: Text('No rides posted yet. Be the first to post a ride!'));
            }
            else{
              return SizedBox(height: 20.0,);
            }
          }
          return SizedBox(height: 20.0,);
        },
      );
    }
  }
}
```

[image: Error]

[image: Error goes away]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `rides` its always a List() that can be null,

you should use the conditional => `if (rides != null)`

instead of => `if (rides.length != null)`.

The error is happing because you have to check first if `rides` it's not null before calling the property `length`.